# why “1 HDFS block per HDFS file” is better in parquet official document ？

Tags: parquet

why “1 HDFS block per HDFS file” is an optimized read setup in parquet official document ？

[parquet official document](https://parquet.apache.org/documentation/latest/)

EDIT:

[image]

As in the figure above, the parquet file is made up of row groups.
if "1GB row groups, 1GB HDFS block size" , then 1 row group will fit 1 HDFS block. Then column will not outside of HDFS block. So, we no longer need to transfer data. But, what is “1 HDFS block per HDFS file” for ?

Comment: I stumpled today to the same official parquet documentation and couldn't find an answer by myself to the same question. I am coming to the same conclusion as you, as long as the row group size is the same as HDFS block size, why should it matter at all to only have 1 Block per 1 HDFS file.
Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially because parquet is a columnar storage format. So lets say that you have stored a 3 GB file with a blocksize of 1GB. To read a whole record  you will need to reconstruct the record if the information of each column is not in a single block (which his probably the case because the columnar format), this mean that  necessarily in one machine will be needed reconstruct the record requiring the data transfer from other nodes to reassembly the record.

EDIT:

For the following image which compare row storage against column storage, imagine  that the column cost doesn't fit in your block size, it means that this column will be outside of your block and will create a new block. If you want to use the data for one whole specific row, the data for the cost column will need to be send for one node to another which is not efficient. I hope it makes sense.

[image]

Comment: "1GB row groups, 1GB HDFS block size" is enough to avoid transferring data, isn't it ?

Comment: You are right, but to accomplish data in columnar storage you will need 1 gb file

Comment: why  need 1 gb file ?

Comment: because to have a 1 GB group you need all the groups in the same block, it  means that you will need all the group in the same file when you use parquet format, if you dont, some columns will be in a different block, it means that you will need transfer the data to reconstruct the records

Comment: As in the figure above, the parquet file is made up of row groups. if "1GB row groups, 1GB HDFS block size" , then 1 row group will fit 1 HDFS block. Then column will not outside of HDFS block. So, we no longer need to transfer data. But, what is “1 HDFS block per HDFS file” for ?

Comment: at least in mapreduce program the general behavior is that each mapper read 1 block of data, for this reason you should try to make your block size as big as your file, in this case 1 GB block size for each 1 GB File, it will ensure that one mapper will read 1 block  without require data transfer to reconstruct records

Comment: A parquet file is made up of row groups。And a row group has all columns.So,a row group can independently reconstruct records in it,dosn't depend on other row groups in the file. 
So,a map need to read a row group,not a file.
Isn't it?